# Graph Theory - Cycles and Colors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I have been working with bipartite, four colorable, and five colorable graphs for a while now, and I came across a problem that I understand visually but not mathematically.
Why is it true that any graph which isn't five colorable must have at least two disjoint cycles? I've tested this out by drawing on paper and it seems to make sense, but I am not sure how to prove this rigorously.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!